# mLAB Insert document into a collection API

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, mlab

Below is the code snippet I am using :

```
request.post('https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/db/collections/coll?apiKey=APIKEY',
                                            { json: {result} },
                                            function (error, response, body) {
                                                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                                                    console.log("----->"+body);
                                                }
                                                else
                                                console.log("-----XXXXX>"+error);   
                                            });
```

Now `result` is a javascript var which is a string and has a proper json stored in it in the below form:

```
{
"key1":"value1",
"key2" : "value2",
....
"key100":"value3"
}
```

**So basically in collection coll I need to insert above json as a document.**

Output of above code is below :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a71c84ac2ef165da041df86"
    },
    "result": "{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":\"val2\"}"

}
```

The above is the Json document that I am getting after executing the piece of NodeJs code shown at top and also I have shown the contents of string result.

I just need at the a json document like below:

```
{
"key1":"val1",
.....
"key100":"val100"
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the error or unexpected result you are seeing?

Comment: see at the end I have attached the output that I am getting which is undesirable.


I want the json document to be like:
{
"_id":{"$oid":"12321321313"},
"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2" 
}


Actually the value of result is a Json document which I need to insert as a whole.

@tfogo

Comment: Sorry, still unsure what the issue is. Is the issue the backslashes in your output?

Comment: That would probably an issue with parsing json. Perhaps `result` isn't getting parsed correctly? Have you confirmed it's an object and not a string?

Comment: yes @tfogo its a string not an object and I need to insert that string's contents  as it is in the Json document. That string's content is a proper Json document.

Comment: You can use `result = JSON.parse(result)` to convert a string to a JSON object. See the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Once result has been parsed, the object should be inserted as a document rather than a string.

Comment: Edited the last part of description to make question more clear.

Comment: Okay, so one issue is you need to convert it from a string to an object. Do you also not want the object to be inserted as the value of the `result` key? Just `{ "_id":{"$oid":"12321321313"}, "key1":"val1", "key2":"val2" }` instead of `{ "_id":{"$oid":"12321321313"}, result: {"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"} }?

Comment: If that's the case, change this `{ json: {result} }` to this `{ json: result }`

Comment: `{ json: {result} }` expands to `{ json: {result: result} }` because of shorthand property names

Comment: @tfogo you are awesome man ! Thanks a ton

Apart from Mongo Docs is there any other resource from where I can lear about this DB in depth

Comment: Happy to help! MongoDB University offers some great courses (https://university.mongodb.com/). And the mLab docs are a good resource for info about your deployment (http://docs.mlab.com/).

Comment: @tfogo can you please check this.
Using $push in MLAB REST API. Please Help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397193/using-push-in-mlabs-mongodb-rest-api?noredirect=1#comment85796368_49397193