# $set in MongoDB : Not working as intended

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mlab

I have the following document in my DB :

```
{
....
"key": "val1",
....
"array" :[
{
"k":"v1",
"rejected":"0"

},
{
"k":"v2",
"rejected":"0"

}

]
.....
}
```

***Now basically I want to set "rejected":"1" for  ("key":"val1" && array[i]."k":"v1" ).***

The API call that I have written is :

```
var val1="val1";
var v1="v1";

    request.put('https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/DB/collections/doc?q={"key": "'+val1+'","array.k":"'+v1+'"}&apiKey=.....',
                        { json: { "$set": {"rejected": "1"}
                        } },
                        function (error, response, body) {
                            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                                console.log("----->Insertion"+body);
                                return res.status(200).send("[{\"status\":\"success\"}]");
                            }
                            else
                            {console.log(JSON.stringify(response));}
                        });
```

But the API instead of editing the needed field,it appends a new field at the end of document:

```
 {
    ....
    "key": "val1",
    ....
    "array" :[
    {
    "k":"v1",
    "rejected":"0"

    },
    {
    "k":"v2",
    "rejected":"0"

    }

    ]
    .....

    "rejected":"1"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case use [db.collection.update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

Mongodb shell query

```
If there is only one matching document

db.collection_name.update(
  {key:"val1", "array.k":"v1"},
  {$set:{"array.$.rejected":"1"}}      
);

If there are multiple documents matching the criteria then use the below query with multi:true

db.collection_name.update(
  {key:"val1", "array.k":"v1"},
  {$set:{"array.$.rejected":"1"}}, 
  {multi:true}
);
```

Update query has three parts

First is the matching part where we have to give

```
"key":"val1" and "array.k": "v1"
```

Second part is to set the updated value

Using $set and positional operator, set the value to be updated
here for matching array.k update rejected as "1"

Final part is to specify if multiple documents are matching the criteria then update all the matching documents

Answer (score 0):

Let say your json object is called as **array**...read about positional operator in mongodb.Then this will update your array element

```
Object.update(
  {'array.key': val1},
  {$set: {'array.$. rejected': 1}},
  function(err, count) { ... });
```

Comment: please help me with the API constructs

Comment: you change the code accordingly or either you can share your full code to me for further debugging

Comment: This is the full code. First Snippet is how my document looks like in DB. Then I have stated what I want to achieve. 2nd Snippet is the API call I am making to do the stuff. Thats it.

Comment: I am not getting that $set part you are doing in that request call ? I think thats wrong.You are only calling API not any mongodb function...